# I am getting tonnes of errors relating to permissions - using WSL2 laravel project. The issue specifically relates to pdo_mysql

Tags: php, bash, pdo, wsl-2

A bit of backstory -

I have a work laptop where my project works totally fine. I have quit my job to pursue expanding my own business, that has become large enough that I can no longer maintain a full time job alongside it. Because of this, I obviously have to give back my work laptop, which is a Macbook. My home machine, is a windows desktop PC.

I have set up my environment using WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04, and I've got everything working so far, save from the fact that when I load up my project, none of the images or CSS are pulling through. I had narrowed this down to the fact that pdo_mysql doesn't seem to be working (Though I'm technically front end, back end I still find confusing so I may be wrong).

I have tried reinstalling pdo_mysql, and I have tried changing permissions of the file.

As a side note - I initially created my new work environment using a symbolic link between the project files on my local Windows and the Linux server but this caused massive delays that made it near unusable (I never fully completed set up and reached near enough the same place as now). Because of this, I removed the link by deleting the link file on the linux server, then deleted the github project and recloned it directly onto the linus server. I don't know if this is important information or not.

I am also getting A LOT of permission errors, despite having tried setting the entire project permissions for my linux user.

This is the error when I run `php -i | grep extension_dir`

```
fantasyroad@Louie:~$ php -i | grep extension_dir
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20210902 => /usr/lib/php/20210902
```

EDIT: Just to make clear - the pdo_mysql file IS located at /usr/lib/php/20210902/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by uninstalling everything php related, then reinstlaling them one by one manually.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).